# Avoid entering backend url manually

Tags: reactjs

I am a backend developer and really novice in react.

In my first project I was able to redirect API calls from react to my backend url by simply adding this to my package.json :

```
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

In my first project I did not use a javascript service class therefore I called API directly in App.js :

```
refreshList = () => {
    axios
      .get("/api/todos/")
      .then((res) => this.setState({ todoList: res.data }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

So this works fine!

In my second project I am using a service class that I call in App.js.
I have added the proxy url to package.json then here is my service class :

```
import axios from "axios";

export default class CustomersService{

   

    getCustomers() {
        return axios.get("/api/customers").then(response => response.data);
    }
    getCustomersByURL(link){
        return axios.get(`/api/customers/${link}`).then(response => response.data);
    }
    getCustomers(pk) {
        return axios.get(`/api/customers/${pk}`).then(response => response.data);
    }
    deleteCustomer(customer){
        return axios.delete(`/api/customers/${customer.pk}`);
    }
    createCustomer(customer){
        return axios.post("/api/customers",customer);
    }
    updateCustomer(customer){
        return axios.put(`/api/customers/${customer.pk}`);
    }
}
```

now when I call the apis in App.js :

```
 <div className="content">
      <Route path="/" exact component={CustomersList} />
      <Route path="/customer/:pk"  component={CustomerCreateUpdate} />
      <Route path="/customer/" exact component={CustomerCreateUpdate} />

    </div>
```

The API is not redirected to my backend it makes a call through my front end port 3000 :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/customers/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

If I add my backend url as a const in my service it works but I guess this is not a best practice, how could I do the same as my first project without having to explicitly se my backend url?

Update after first answer to clarify the question :

Here is the document I found :

The proxy will help in tunneling API requests to http://localhost:8000 where the Django application will handle them. Without this proxy, you would need to specify full paths:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/todos/")
```

With proxy, you can provide relative paths:

```
axios.get("/api/todos/")
```

So even using the .env file I could pass it to proxy :

proxy = env.BACKEND_URL;
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend-URL shouldn't be stored in package.json because it's related to your app dependencies-scripts and the values are public if your app is open source, instead, it should be stored as an environment variable "in .env file" and could be set to development value that you use locally in `.env.local`

So create two files

`.env` that the values will be injected in your deployment service you use "by injecting values in a dashboard"

`.env.local` that should be added in .gitignore and each developer could add use his own value

Read more about `.env` files in react

[Adding Custom Environment variable CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Access it like this

```
// in .env
BACKENDURL=www.example.com


// in service for example
getCustomers() {
        return axios.get(`${process.env.BACKENDURL}/api/customers`).then(response => response.data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as you can see in my first project I don't pass the url when I try to access the API and I wonder if this is possible in the second case, the .env is indeed usefull but as you mentioned in your code you are still passing the variable for the url in the get call.

Comment: Are you able to do it with `fetch API`, have you tried this [Axios Proxy](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072#issuecomment-567473812)

Comment: I use Axios yes. It seems that passing the URL as a const is a widley used practice I will stick with it

Comment: Give this a try please, [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072#issuecomment-567473812)